Why am I getting extremely slow when transferring data from external HDD to computer?
When transferring data from my external HDD to the computer or transferring to another external hard disk, it constantly stays at 0 bytes, even a 2-3 gb file is transferred after hours.
So I started this problem HDD (1TB WD Elements HDD) with Windows own tool "optimise" option hours ago and now the transition: In stage 2 it is still defragmenting. and I don't know when it will end.
My question is:

In this case, does optimising, i.e. defragmenting, an extremely slow transferring hdd fix this situation?
Will I lose any data with this optimisation option?
Apart from these, I am open to any suggestions from the community to solve this problem.


We don't know. Is it a USB2 or USB3 drive and did you connect it to USB2 or USB3 port?

USB Version: 3.0
3.0 port.
but I'm still facing this situation.@Justme

So is the cable an USB3 cable? Has the cable or any connector been damaged so there is only a USB2 link? Or is there a USB3 link?
